# Drawing a Triangle Component using pen operation

Tags: java, swing

How to do it? I mean, I can do it for Ellipse, but not sure about triangle.

Comment: `Graphics.drawPolygon(...)`

Comment: I tried that but it would only draw lines

Comment: 3 lines make a triangle, so you need to combine the 3 lines into the polygon.

Comment: I showed you how to do painting properly by using a BufferedImage so you don't use the getGraphics() method of the panel and you just deleted the answer. I showed you how to read a file using ImageIO and you ignored the suggestion only asking for me to write the code for you.  I guess you need to somehow set a state in your program and then the next 3 mouse clicks will be used to get the points of the triangle. Then you use the points to draw the image. I have never done this so its up to you do give it a try and post a specific question when you have a problem.

Comment: @camickr: Sorry. I don't understand some of your code, although I really appreciate the effort. It's way beyond my level.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Polygon`.

```
int[] xPoints = {0, 0, 30};
int[] yPoints = {0, 30, 30};
Shape s = new Polygon(xPoints, yPoints, 3);
g2d.fill(s);
```

Comment: Can you post the mouse drag and released operations please?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your current question.

It demonstrates why you should NOT use panel.getGraphics() to do your painting. Painting done with the getGraphics() method is not permanent.

Try minimizing or maximizing the frame and see what happens to the painting:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SSCCE2
{
    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel()
        {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                super.paintComponent(g);

                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.fillOval(0, 0, 50, 50);
            }
        };

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible( true );

        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(100, 100, 50, 50);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillOval(100, 100, 50, 50);
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```